# How can I escape *all* characters into their corresponding html entity names and numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-entities

I wanted to encode a string to its corresponding html entities but unfortunately I am not able to. As I said in question title, I want *all* characters in a string to be converted into their corresponding html entity(both numbers and names). So according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html). I tried:

```
In [31]: import html

In [32]: s = '<img src=x onerror="javascript:alert("XSS")">'

In [33]: html.escape(s)
Out[33]: '&lt;img src=x onerror=&quot;javascript:alert(&quot;XSS&quot;)&quot;&gt;'
```

But I want all characters to be converted and not just '<' , '>', '&' ,etc.
And also `html.escape` only gives html entity *names* and not numbers but I want both.

But surprisingly [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) unescapes all entities into their corresponding characters.

```
In [34]: a = '<img src=x onerror="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#000005
    ...: 8&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">'

In [35]: html.unescape(a)
Out[35]: '<img src=x onerror="javascript:alert(\'XSS\')">'
```

So can I do the same with [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape)?

I am really surprised why *all* resources on internet for encoding and decoding html entities are not encoding all chars and also the php `htmlspecialchars()` function don't do that. And I don't want to write all html entity numbers from [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) character by character.

Comment: Did you forget some semicolons in your escaped string?

Comment: @MadPhysicist In `a` variable? I don't think so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure html entities are supposed to end in a semicolon

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, but they are _intentionally_ omitted see [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: That's neat. I was wondering what you were up to ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need a special function for what you are doing because the numbers you want are just the Unicode code points of the characters in question.

[`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) does pretty much what you want:

```
 def encode(s):
     return ''.join('&#{:07d};'.format(ord(c)) for c in s)
```

Aesthetically, I prefer hex encoding:

```
 def encode(s):
     return ''.join('&#x{:06x};'.format(ord(c)) for c in s)
```

What is special about [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) and [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) is that they support named entities in addition to the numerical ones. The goal of escaping is normally to turn your string into something that doesn't have characters special to the HTML parser, so `escape` only replaces a handful of characters. What you are doing ensures that all characters in the string are ASCII in addition to that.

If you want to force the use of named entities wherever possible, you can check the [`html.entities.codepoint2name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.entities.html#html.entities.codepoint2name) mapping after applying `ord` to the characters:

```
def encode(s):
    return ''.join('&{};'.format(codepoint2name.get(i, '#{}'.format(i))) for i in map(ord, s))
```

Comment: One clarification: As you said those characters in the string should be ASCII but `ord` documentation says they can be any unicode character and also the page I linked _do_ have characters which are not ASCII. right?

Comment: The _output_ of `ord` will be all ascii, not the input.

Comment: The output of `ord` is an integer, which is then represented as a string containing exclusively ASCII.